# Стиль в UserControl

Tags: c#, wpf

Есть UserControl

ModernBtn.xaml

```
<Button x:Class="ModernButton.ModernBTN"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
         xmlns:local="clr-namespace:ModernButton"
         mc:Ignorable="d" 
         d:DesignHeight="100" d:DesignWidth="200" Name="myBtn" Background="Transparent">
<Button.Style>
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate>
                    <Border Background="{Binding ElementName=myBtn, Path=ButtonColor}" CornerRadius="{Binding ElementName=myBtn, Path=CornerRadius}" Name="mainBorder">
                        <Grid>
                            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                <RowDefinition Height="*"></RowDefinition>
                                <RowDefinition Height="Auto"></RowDefinition>
                            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding ElementName=myBtn, Path=BtnText}" FontSize="25" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Foreground="{Binding ElementName=myBtn, Path=ForeColor}"></TextBlock>
                            <Rectangle Fill="Lime" Height="5" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Margin="0,0,0,20" Name="indicatorBtn" Width="0"></Rectangle>
                        </Grid>
                    </Border>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
</Button.Style>
```

И когда в Window1.xaml я контроллу присваиваю Style

> ModernButton:ModernBtn Style={StaticResource DefaultButtonStyle}>

То получается первоначальный стиль контролла меняется на тот который я поставил.
Как можно при установление свойства Style у контролла сделать так что-бы этот стиль наследовался от первоначального стиля.

Тоесть когда я в Window1.xaml у ModernBtn прописываю Style (Background,Foreground и тд) 
что-бы стиль этой кнопки становился таким каким я его прописал в Window1.xaml но еще и свойство ControlTemplate (от первоначального стиля).

Answer (score 0):

Наследование стиля, это немного другой механизм. Вы в ресурсах окна или кнопки объявляете новый стиль и указываете, что он наследует от стиля DefaultButtonStyle:

```
<Style BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type DefaultButtonStyle}}" TargetType="Button" x:Key="ChangedButtonStyle">
```

В нем переопределяете только те свойства которые надо переопределить и у кнопки устанавливаете именно этот переопределенный стиль.

Второй вариант, вы переопределяете не при помощи стилей, а задавая значения свойств Background,Foreground и тд непосредственно у кнопки. В этом случае, такое назначение будет иметь более высокий приоритет. Более подробно про стили можете прочитать [здесь](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/framework/wpf/controls/styling-and-templating).